# Bandwidth limit Cisco 3400 ME problem

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, bandwidth, troubleshooting, policy-map

I want to limit bandwidth (speed) of interface of Cisco 3400 ME switch.

I did these:

```
policy-map parent
class class-default
shape average 64000
```

And in `gi0/2` interface I apply it: `service-policy output parent`

It gives me this error:

```
QoS: Configuration failed. The configured rate 64000 bps is not achievable in within 1% of configuration.
Closest value(s) are: 11111120 bps, 5882368 bps
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I limit bandwidth of gigabit interface to 64 kbit/s?

Comment: What IOS version are you using? Please post output of `show version`.

Comment: You did perform nothing wrong, it is some limitation of model. You can google "achievable in hw within 1% of configuration" and check a lot of articles about this.
As I understand, you can try to use 10Mbps speed on the link for using 100Kbps (1%) for shaping, but no less.

Comment: @KonstantinGoncharenko, there is no speed command appliable, because it is SFP port.

Comment: @Cown, IOS version: (ME340x-METROBASE-M) Version 12.2(53)SE

Comment: @itdev read the answer. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: @Cown, really? But what does bandwidth command do?

Comment: @itdev The command bandwidth only sets the minimum reserved bandwidth on an interface. So if you set it to 64 Kbit/s, the interface will have that reserved in case it gets congested.

Comment: @Cown, thanks. It means that we have to upgrade IOS or hardware itself

Comment: @itdev you will have to upgrade the hardware. The problem exists on all software releases due to a hardware limitation in the ME 3400. Problem is solved on the Cisco ME 3400-E (enhanced).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you describe is explained by Tassos (CCIE #19858) in the attached link below. I've copied his complete description and added the Cisco bug which relates to the problem you have.

Please notice, that the issue has been fixed on the newer enhanced ME 3400-E.

> Everyone using ME-3400 switches might have noticed the following error
>   message when trying to configure an output policy-map under an
>   interface:

```
QoS: Configuration failed.  The configured rate 4000000 bps is not 
achievable in hw within 1% of configuration.
         Closest value(s) are: 11111120 bps, 5882368 bps
```

> Cisco documentation is cryptic (as always) about the details of this,
>   but it has to do with some hardware limitation of this specific
>   platform. In particular the granularity of the hardware for the
>   shaping action is somehow based on pre-configured values.
>
> The ME-3400 (as most lower end switches) has physical memory buffers,
>   which can be used by IOS only in bunches of specific (pre-configured)
>   sizes. In routers and high end switches, QoS is usually implemented in
>   software through the use of memory pools, which allows the IOS to use
>   parts of buffers with variable sizes.
>
> Egress shaping on ME-3400 comes into two categories : Port shaping and
>   Class-based shaping. Port shaping applies to all traffic passing
>   through an interface, while class-based shaping applies to specific
>   classes of traffic leaving an interface. Each one of them is using a
>   different formula in order to give you all the supported values.
>
> Port shaping values are based on the following formula:

```
(1 - 16/N) * IfSpeed
```

> Where:
>
> N is a value between 17 and 64000 IfSpeed is the interface speed : 10
>   Mbps, 100 Mbps, 1 Gbps The result in then rounded up to a multiple of
>   16. An equivalent excel formula would be : CEILING((1-16/N)*IfSpeed;16)
>
> Class-based shaping values are based on the following much simpler
>   formula:

```
1/N * IfSpeed
```

> Where: N is a value between 1 and 15625 IfSpeed is the interface speed
>   : 10 Mbps, 100 Mbps, 1 Gbps
>
> You can see some possible values in the table below:
>
> According to the above table, in the port shaper the low end
>   granularity is very coarse and the high end granularity is very dense,
>   while the opposite happens in the class-based shaper. So there is no
>   possibility you can have a <58 Mbps port shaper for 1 Gbps interfaces,
>   as there is no possibility to have <5,8 Mbps port shaper for 100 Mbps
>   interfaces. Similarly you can't have a 700 Mbps class-based shaper on
>   a 1000 Mbps interface, nor a 80 Mbps class-based shaper on a 100 Mbps
>   interface.
>
> Let's take for example the following policy-map configuration which is
>   applied on a 1 Gbps interface.

```
 policy-map CHILD  class TEST-CLASS
     shape average 100000 policy-map PARENT  class class-default
     shape average 930000000   service-policy CHILD
```

> If you try to change the shaper of the child class to a value >500
>   Mbps, you'll get a warning like the following:

```
 3400(config-pmap-c)#shape average 700000000 QoS: Configuration failed.
 The configured rate 700000000 bps is not achievable in hw within 1% of
 configuration.
         Closest value(s) are: 930000000 bps, 500000000 bps
```

> If you check the formula for the class-based shaper (or have a quick
>   look at the table), 930000000 is not actually a valid value to
>   configure, but it gets printed because this is the limit imposed by
>   the parent class. You just have to ignore it.
>
> If you need specific values you might want to try changing the speed
>   of the interface : choosing between 10/100/1000 should be easy for
>   BaseTX interfaces, while 100/1000 Mbps SFPs exist for the SFP-based
>   ones.
>
> Also, it's strongly recommended that you disable port speed
>   autonegotiation when you attach an output policy map to a 10/100/1000
>   port, to prevent the port from autonegotiating to a rate that would
>   make the output policy map invalid.
>
> Keep in mind that ME-3400E (the new enhanced version of ME-3400)
>   implements a improved version of Egress Shaping Granularity, which
>   uses a simpler linear formula. It's 64 Kbps for the class-based shaper
>   and 100/500/1000 Kbps for the 10/100/1000 Mbps port-based shaper (100
>   Kbps for 10 Mbps ports, 500 Kbps for 100 Mbps ports, 1000 Kbps for
>   1000 Mbps ports).

**Cisco bug report for those who do not have access to Cisco:**

**ME3400 - inconsistent rate for hw shaper when queue-limit is changed
CSCsz52950**

> Description
>
> Symptom:
>
> If the queue-limit is configured on a policy-map with a shaper
>   attached the suggested configurabale rate gets changed.

```
policy-map test-shaper
 class class-default
    shape average 35000000

lan-me3400-1(config-pmap-c)#int g0/11
lan-me3400-1(config-if)#service-policy output test-shaper
QoS: Configuration failed.  The configured rate 35000000 bps is not achievable in hw within 1% of configuration.
        Closest value(s) are: 36000000 bps, 33333344 bps
```

> Error using the default 160 packet queue  [EXPECTED MESSAGE DUE TO
>   GRANULARITY - THIS IS NOT THE BUG]
>
> ========================================
>
> Queue limit is changed to any value (therefore not to default any
>   more)

```
policy-map test-shaper
 class class-default
    shape average 35000000
    queue-limit 200

lan-me3400-1(config-pmap-c)#int g0/11
lan-me3400-1(config-if)#
lan-me3400-1(config-if)#service-policy output test-shaper
QoS: Configuration failed.  The configured rate 35000000 bps is not achievable in hw within 1% of configuration.
        Closest value(s) are: 33333333 bps, 25000000 bps
```

> Conditions:
>
> Queue-limit is expressely defined.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Use the suggested value.
>
> Further Problem Description:
>
> The message is cosmetic as at hardware level there is no change when
>   the queue-limit is configured.

Tassos source: https://ccie-in-3-months.blogspot.com/2010/01/shaper-granularity-on-me-3400.html

Cisco bug search (requires CCO login): https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCsz52950